# Column not changing to numeric from chr

Tags: r, binary, character, numeric

```
house = read.csv("Final dataset.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
house_bin = house[39:55]
str(house_bin)
house_bin[house_bin == "N"] = as.integer(0)
house_bin[house_bin == "Y"] = as.integer(1)
str(house_bin)
library(polycor)
library(psych)
tetrachoric(house_bin)
```

I have some categorical variables in my data frame which have a value of either "Y" or "N". I changed them to binary (1 and 0) as you can see above. However, the data type of the data or column is still chr.

I have tried changing it to numeric by using below methods but no luck!

```
house_bin = as.numeric(house_bin)
house_bin = as.numeric(as.character(house_bin))
house_bin = (as.numeric(unlist(house_bin)))
house_bin = apply(house_bin,2,as.numeric)
```

The structure (str) before turning them to 1 or 0

```
str(house_bin)
'data.frame':   5764 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ Mobile.Home.Indicator                    : chr  "N" "N" "Y" "N" ...
 $ Single.Parent                            : chr  "N" "N" "N" "N" ...
 $ Fireplace.in.Home                        : chr  "N" "Y" "Y" "N" ...
 $ Pool.Owner                               : chr  "N" "N" "N" "Y" ...
```

The structure (str) after turning them to 1 or 0

```
str(house_bin)
'data.frame':   5764 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ Mobile.Home.Indicator                    : chr  "0" "0" "1" "0" ...
 $ Single.Parent                            : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ Fireplace.in.Home                        : chr  "0" "1" "1" "0" ...
 $ Pool.Owner                               : chr  "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
```

Comment: Do you get an error or warning message when using Check to make sure there aren't any values in the columns other than "0" and "1."  You can use summary(as.factor(house_bin)) to see the counts of all distinct values.  If every value in the column is a 1 or a 0,  as.numeric() should work.

Comment: > summary(as.factor(house_bin))
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?     I get the above error

Comment: Yes, R. Schifini is absolutely right.  Because you converted the yes's and no's separately, you ended up with non-atomic data in the column. (Two separate data types in the same column), which is probably why you're getting that error.  Glad his solution worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are replacing "N" and "Y" in two separate commands. When the first one is replaced (N for 0L) the 0L is converted to character because the "Y" characters are still there.

One way to do it is using `ifelse`. Let's set up an example:

```
df = data.frame(c = c("N","Y"),d = c("Y","N"),stringsAsFactors = F)

> df
  c d
1 N Y
2 Y N

> str(df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ c: chr  "N" "Y"
 $ d: chr  "Y" "N"
```

Using `ifelse`:

```
df = data.frame(ifelse(df=="N",0L,1L))
```

Result:

```
> df
  c d
1 0 1
2 1 0

> str(df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ c: int  0 1
 $ d: int  1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone. The code from R.Schifini fixed my problem

```
df = data.frame(ifelse(df=="N",0L,1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a number of different ways, but here's an example using `dplyr`.

#### create data

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(a = sample(c("Y", "N"), 10, replace = TRUE),
             b = sample(c("Y", "N"), 10, replace = TRUE),
             c = sample(c("Y", "N"), 10, replace = TRUE))
df

#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>        a     b     c
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1     Y     Y     Y
#>  2     Y     N     N
#>  3     Y     N     Y
#>  4     Y     Y     Y
#>  5     Y     Y     Y
#>  6     Y     Y     N
#>  7     Y     N     N
#>  8     Y     N     N
#>  9     N     N     Y
#> 10     Y     Y     N
```

#### Recode character to numeric

[`dplyr::mutate_at`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) is nice because you can specify which columns to operate on easily in the first `vars()` argument with any of these [select helpers](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select_helpers.html). Then you can use [`dplyr::recode`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/recode.html) to clearly change the `"Y"` and `"N"` to binary in the second `funs()`argument.

```r
df %>% mutate_at(vars(a, b, c), funs(recode(., "Y" = 1L, "N" = 0L)))

#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>        a     b     c
#>    <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     0     0     0
#>  2     0     0     0
#>  3     0     0     1
#>  4     1     0     0
#>  5     1     0     1
#>  6     1     0     1
#>  7     1     1     1
#>  8     1     1     0
#>  9     0     0     0
#> 10     0     0     0
```

Another option that gives the same result is to use [`dplyr::mutate_if`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) to select the columns to operate on with a predicate function. This might be more helpful in your case. Here it only recodes character variables.

```r
df %>% mutate_if(is.character, funs(recode(., "Y" = 1L, "N" = 0L)))
```